# jQuery validation engine always failing validation with select2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine, jquery-select2

I am running into a strange issue where, instead of it not validating at all using the pos absolute jquery validation engine plugin, the field is over-validating aka, we are always getting the "Field is required" prompt.

Here is my html:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label for="funeral_director" class="control-label">Funeral Director</label>

    <div class="controls">
        <select name="funeral_director" id="funeral_director" class="validate[required]">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="13">Test User</option>
            <option value="4">Admin User</option>
            <option value="1">Dev User</option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my select2 javascript:

```
$('#funeral_director').select2({
    blurOnChange: true,
    placeholder: 'Director',
    width: 'resolve'
});
```

And here is my validation engine javascript:

```
$("#addForm").validationEngine({
                prettySelect: true,
                usePrefix: 's2id_'
            });
```

I don't think it matters as I also tried moving the select2 instantiation into the same file both before and after the validation instantiation., but both lots of javascript are getting called in `$(function(){/*..code*/})` blocks, but in separate files, the validation engine initialization file is included before the select2 initialization file.

Select2: 3.3.1
jqve: 2.6.2

Comment: If I call `$('#funeral_director').val()` or `$('#funeral_director').select2('val')` they both return `"4"` if I have selected Admin User.

Answer (score 0):

In **select2.min.js** find this strokes (should be 2 strokes in script):

`D(this.container,this.opts.element,this.opts.adaptContainerCssClass)`

and add this code right after stroke you've found

`,this.container.removeClass("validate[required]")`

this should solve your problem.